# VBA excel calculating in userform

Tags: vba, combobox, userform

i have a userform that includes combox and two textboxes
the user choose a chemical (text) from the combobox1 and enters the height of the chemical in textbox1 (number).
then according to the chemical he choose i define the density and area of the tank of the chemical.
then i need to calculate: textbox2.value=density*area*textbox1.value
density and area are different for every chemical.
the equation is mass=density*area*volume.
i tried this code:
    Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    Dim chem As String

```
chem = ComboBox1.Value
    mychem

End Sub
Sub mychem()
Dim density As Double
Dim volume As Double

If chem = "Sodium" Then
area = 22
density = 1.058
End If
If chem = "HCl 9%" Then
area = 22
density = 1.043
End If
If chem = "alum" Then
area = 70
density = 1.163
End If
If IsNumeric(Txtheight.Text) Then
                txtmass.Value = density *area * CDbl   (Txtheight.Value)

                   End If
end sub
```

Answer (score 0):

density and volume are variables, they don't have a `Value` property.

```
TextBox4.Value = CDbl(density) * CDbl(volume) * CDbl(TextBox8.Value)
```

Also, density and volume are already Doubles, you don't need to convert them with CDbl.

And you should take the time to rename your controls. I would suggest `txtHeight` but your description isn't clear about whether the textbox contains the height, area or volume(?).

Comment: thanks, now the calculation works with no bug. but it gives answer 0. i'm guessing that the code doesnt define my variables currectly.